# Add input and submit field in google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have multiple markers on my google map, user has to enter some notes when they click and open the marker infowindow.  There will a textbox and submit button, I want to get the value from the input box.

```js
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park.'+
     
      '</div><input type="text"><button>submit</button>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCGzw8fgSuNnFhem_sQ6OmnaqvcczlMbtk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Please check the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/sankarmahadevan/vjce1w63/6/

Comment: 1) And the problem is? 2) I don't see **any** attempt to *get the value from the input box* in the code you posted.

Comment: I have found the solution, updated in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sankarmahadevan/vjce1w63/11/

Answer (score 0):

I did the following updates, I added listener for google map domready and added button click function.

Updated fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sankarmahadevan/vjce1w63/11/)

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    isGoogleDomReady(infowindow);
  });

function isGoogleDomReady(infowindow){
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {         
            $('#SaveBtn').on('click', function() {              
                alert($('#mapNotes').val());                
            });
        });
    }
```